# stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString

Tags: swift, uiwebview

i write app and i need load same HTML page. Than need take element.

> getElementById(\"orderData\")

```
let webView = UIWebView()       
let localfilePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("PrintPage", withExtension: "html") 

let myRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: localfilePath!)    
webView.loadRequest(myRequest)  

print(webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document"))
```

But just print document give me **Optional""**. 
getElementById(\"orderData\") too write **Optional""**.

P.S. I can see this page, no problem with loading.

------ Update
P.S.S Deal not in OptionValue =) Deal with empty string when i try use JavaScript

Comment: A good way to learn Swift is to study Apple's Swift ebook. Also use the online reference, it's very good. The part about Optionals: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330 (you *really* want to read this).

Answer (score 0):

In Swift if you print an `Optional` value then it prints with **Optional""**, if you don't want to print with Optional then you can use following code.

```
if let docString = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document") {
     print(docString)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` method return optional string `String?` .
   It will print `Optional""` in output.

You need to Refer [Optional Chaining in swift language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html)